# Upgrading GLX to version 1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia, glfw, glx

I have the following question: for the purpose of visualisation of some point clouds with GLFW library and Open3D, I would like to upgrade GLX to version 1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. Having done some research on the Internet, I applied the most commonly advised solution:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

but to no avail - `glxinfo | grep version`  still yields 1.2. Could it be driver-related? My graphics card is GeForce RTX 2070 and my driver is 460.32.03. I also seem to have the newest version of the Mesa library.
I am running out of ideas and will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: How about a reboot?

Comment: @Roadowl Already done, to no avail. In the meantime, it was pointed out to me that the xorg-edgers PPA was not the right way to go, as Ubuntu 18.04 is not supported by it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put

```
 java -Dprism.order=sw -jar yourjar.jar
```

While executing it.